# CakePHP 1.3: set automatice logout manually

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

How to set automaticlogout time in cakephp?
Currnetly I am using this code in core.php file
here I want to set time 10 min , means if site be idol 10 min then session should be expire after 10 min. but it is not working proper. please explain.

```
Configure::write('Session.timeout', '60');
Configure::write('Security.level', 'high');
```

Answer (score 0):

On my install, the timeout number translates to 100 seconds. So 10 minutes for me would be
Configure::write( 'Session.timeout', '6' );

I use medium security though, rather than high.